# Lost transparency in KDE after installing fglrx video driver

Tags: ati, kubuntu, kde, fglrx

The transparency of KDE panel , Kickoff menu & tooltips were gone just after installing the fglrx display driver

- Folder view plasmoid remains transparent (Looks like before).
- Kwin animations are functioning fine too.
- Kickoff Application Menu now fades in, rather than raising up from bottom.

I'm on  Kubuntu 13.04

[image]

Any idea, would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it back.....!
I removed the fglrx driver, installed fglrx-update and created a new user account.